# Returning a value with a state monad

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm new to Monads and Haskell in general and trying to understand how to return a value when using them. My code looks something like the following:

```
foo :: A -> B
foo a = do  b <- fooC a (C 0)
            -- want to return just (B "b")

fooC :: A -> C -> State MyState B
fooC a c = return (B "b")
```

I tried using `snd (snd b)`, but apparently `State MyState B` is not a tuple? How can I return  the desired value `(B "b")`?

**Edit**: Taking Daniel's advice into account, the rewrite looks like this:

```
data MyState = MyState String
data C = C Int
foo :: String -> String
-- want to return just "b"
foo a = evalState (fooC a) (C 0)

fooC :: String -> Int -> State MyState String
fooC a c = return "b"
```

That still results in a compilation error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `State s0 String'
            with actual type `Int -> State MyState String'
In the return type of a call of `fooC'
Probable cause: `fooC' is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of `evalState', namely `(fooC a)'
In the expression: evalState (fooC a) (C 0)
```

**Edit 2**: Fixed! Final version looks as follows:

```
import Control.Monad.State
data MyState = MyState String
data C = C Int
foo :: String -> String
-- want to return just (B "b")
foo a = evalState (fooC a (C 0)) (MyState "whatever")

fooC :: String -> C -> State MyState String
fooC a c = return "b"

main = print(foo("test"))
-- prints "b"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is

```
foo a = evalState (fooC a (C 0)) (MyState "whatever")
```

You construct the `State MyState B` action `fooC a (C 0)`, unwrap it to get a function, and apply that function to an initial state. Since the state isn't used in this example, you could here also use `undefined` instead of `MyState "whatever"`, but in general, you need to provide a meaningful initial state.

`State MyState B` is not a tuple, it is isomorphic to a function

```
MyState -> (B, MyState)
```

but that function is wrapped in a `newtype` (details vary by monad transformer library package and version), so to access the result of that function applied to an initial state, you need an unwrapping function. For `State`, there are

```
runState :: State s r -> (s -> (r,s))
```

which gives you the function returning the pair,

```
evalState :: State s r -> (s -> r)
```

that gives you the function composed with `fst`, so the final state is discarded, and

```
execState :: State s r -> (s -> s)
```

that composes the function with `snd`, so only the final state is returned.

Comment: Oops, sorry parse failure on my part. Updated.